# How to avoid anonymous function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, frontend

I have a scenario here

```
const Parent = () => {
    handleClick = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
    }
    return <div>
        users.map((user, index) => 
        <child key={index} onClick={(user.id)=>handleClick(user.id)} />)
    </div>
}
```

The child is using React.memo so it won’t re-render unless its props are changed. I don’t want the child to be re-render when the parent renders but in this scenario it will re-render because I am using an anonymous function. I can put **handleClick** inside of **useCallback**  but how can I avoid the anonymous function here. I have to use an anonymous function here because I am expecting some arguments here.

Comment: May you show us an example where you don’t pass an anonymous function?

Comment: In the child component itself, whenever simulate the click, invoke `props.onClick` and pass the id. So that you can get rid of the anonymous function in the parent.

Comment: "I don’t want the child to be re-render" why bother? How many child components do you have? Most likely this is premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `bind`.

```
const Parent = () => {
    handleClick = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
    }
    return <div>
        users.map((user, index) => 
        <Child key={index} onClick={handleClick.bind(this, user.id)} />)
    </div>
}
```

Here's the relevant section of the React docs: [Passing Arguments to Event Handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Comment: The bind() method creates a new function so is not performant, just like creating an anonymous lambda function. This will cause a re-render of the child component, so it might be good to consider memoizing the function depending on how heavy the child component is.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, this is the approach I would take (in case it helps somebody else)

1. Add an attribute to the element, which contains the argument you want to pass as value, e.g `id={user.id}`
2. Then just pass the name of the handler in the `onClick` attribute, and extract the attributes from the `event.target` in your handler function

**NOTE**: you don't have to pass the `event` argument, thus no need to build an anonymous function

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const {id} = event.target
    console.log(id)
  }
  return users.map((user, index) => 
        <div key={index} id={user.id} onClick={handleClick}>{user.name}</div>)
}
```